# Why doesn't Windows 7 System Recovery detect an OS?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I'm working on an HP laptop that experienced a crash of some kind. The user was unable to give me details about the crash. If I turn the Hard Drive into an external (USB) drive, I can read all of the partitions and files on a different computer. However, when the Hard Drive is installed in the original computer, and I boot into a Windows 7 Pro (64-bit) installation (via USB), Windows recovery does not detect an OS.

Here's a list of what I've tried so far:

- Ran HP Hardware diagnostics quick tests. No issues were found. *It is probably not a hardware problem.*
- Ran the [Boot Repair Disc](https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/). No issues were found.
- Ran "check" on the Windows partition using G Parted. Inconsistencies in some of the NTFS volume sectors were found but not fixed. The message recommended that I run "chkdsk /f".
- Ran "chkdsk /f" on all partitions. No issues were listed, but it did say that some repairs were made.
- Ran an "sfc /scannow" command pointing to the external drive. No integrity violations were found.
- Marked the Windows partition as active using DiskPart.
- Marked the System partition as active using DiskPart.
- Marked the boot flag on the Windows partition in GParted.
- Marked the boot flag on the System partition in GParted.

None of the above fixes have worked. I would like to try using bootrec to rebuild the MBR, but I can only use that utility in Windows System Recovery, which does not detect an OS. I have not figured out a way to run bootrec commands on an external Hard Drive.

Why doesn't Windows 7 System Recovery detect an OS?

Comment: "Why doesn't Windows 7 System Recovery detect an OS?"  Because the part(s) that identify the data on the harddisk as being a bootable/usable Windows install have been corrupted/destroyed.

Comment: What parts are you referring to? Can you be more specific or point me in the right direction?

Comment: There's too many possible reasons for it, and may parts that could be the cause.  Is Windows SEEING the drive, but not the OS?  If it's not seeing the drive _at all_, you may have to provide hard drive controller drivers.

Comment: The drive is readable because I can mount it externally and read all partitions and files. I can also mount (and read) it while it is internally installed in the laptop using Lubuntu. I also updated my post to include that I ran an sfc scan from a different computer, but I pointed it to the Windows installation on the external drive. No integrity violations were found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows 7 installation I was using did not have the drivers necessary to detect the hard drive. I found the Windows 7 installer provided by HP. When I boot from HP's disc, the Windows installer detects the drive. In this case, there were no messages indicating that additional drivers were needed.